# The Wi-Fi signal quality of my computer is low being far from Wi-Fi modem (it is good on other devices)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, internet-connection

I am having problems with Internet connection of my laptop. I am not a pro on this topic so please ask me any question if I am not clear.

After having led to repair my notebook for a problem that had nothing to do with Wi-Fi, I started having problems with my wireless connection. I have a Positivo BGH E955 with Windows 10 and *Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC*. I have installed the drivers from the manufacturer's webpage:

http://www.positivobgh.com/productos/soporte/E955x/d#support_drivers

[image: Drivers that I have installed]

Restarted the PC does not work.

Something interesting is that the signal:

[image: Signal]

changes quite frequently being in the same place. Most of the time is as the image above, and sometimes has full signal when I visit webpages using Google Chrome:

[image: Example of signal change]

I use the laptop on some rooms of my house. A very simple sketch:

[image: Places where I use my PC]

Also if I disconnect from the Wi-Fi I get a high signal for a few moments:

[image: Example]

I get the same result when sometimes the Wi-Fi signal changes to [image: example]. Windows found a problem called **"Problem with the network adapter"** (if I remember correctly), and then the signal changes to high.

When I move the PC from the kitchen to the Wi-Fi Modem you can see how the signal intensity changes from low to high instantly.

Also I followed these steps:

1. Press Windows Key + X.
2. Click on Device Manager.
3. Network Adapters.
4. Click Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC -> Properties.
5. Click on Advanced Options. Image:

[image: Advanded Options]

I can't find the option *Antenna Diversity* so I can't change its value.

This problem does not occur on other devices such as my phone, the Smart TV etc.

**What is the issue and how can I solve it?**

Comment: Wireless Mode = Automatic.

Comment: I assume the devices with stronger Wi-Fi signals are closer than your computer. I see this issue here my Wi-Fi router in my basement and my Office on the second floor. I put in a Ubiquity Wireless Access point here connected to my network gear in the basement. This gives me strong signal strength upstairs.

Comment: @John thank you for your quick answer! No, the devices with stronger Wi-Fi signals can or cannot be closer than my computer. The signal is the same (high) when for example: my computer is next to the Wi-Fi Modem and my smartphone is like 2-3m far from the Modem.

Comment: Try a high quality external USB Wi-Fi adapter to see if that improves your PC Reception

Comment: @John how can I get one? Is hardware or software? I think the problem might be the antenna or the "Network adapter", which I don't know what it is or how can I access to it.

Comment: I can't explain how when visiting some webpages the Wi-Fi signal changes... It is weird.

Comment: Check Amazon for USB Wi-Fi adapters and look at the specifications for reception range.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal @John. I am seeing the USB device. It is like an amplifier. That does not solve the problem since we don't know why the signal is low. Also it costs me one USB port (it has 3), and I need all of them. It can solve the main issue. I am looking for a software solution, if possible.

Comment: Only a better Wi-Fi driver (if there is one) can help. Other software does not do anything for reception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this happened after a repair, it seems most likely the problem is due to a hardware issue, such as a loose wire from the Realtek WiFi adapter.

First, to exclude *all* software issues, create a USB flash drive with an alternative "live" operating system (OS), such as Linux. A [USB drive with Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0), for example, can be created and tested in less than an hour. There is *no need to actually install the OS* on your PC; just run from the USB to see if WiFi operates correctly.

If, as I think likely, you have the same issue under Linux as when running under Windows 10, then you've confirmed that it really is *hardware* that needs to be fixed. In that case, bring it back to the repair shop, since it appears the issue was caused there. If you *must* fix this yourself, find a repair or maintenance manual for your Positivo BGH E955 online, either [from the manufacturer](http://www.positivobgh.com/products/Notebooks/Serie-E) or elsewhere. An alternative is to find disassembly instructions, perhaps as a video, similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPQporIBadk). Look for the location of the Realtek chip, and note the routing of wires, one of which might serve as an antenna. Ordinary cellophane tape can be used to hold the antenna in position.

However, if the laptop works well under another OS, you've confirmed the issue is in the OS and/or drivers, *not* hardware. You might try the following:

[image: Device Mgr - uninstall adapter]

- **Make a disk image in case the drivers below cannot be reinstalled.**
- **Connect by Ethernet cable**, because you'll need to download drivers without WiFi.
- Open *Device Manager*: press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `device man`, and select *Device Manager*.
- Uninstall the network controller(s).
- Click the *Scan for Hardware Changes* button.
- Let Windows find the appropriate driver(s) online.
- Retest the WiFi.

On the third hand, if the alternate OS works well, and you like it, then install it ith or instead of Windows.

Comment: Thank you for such complete answer!! I have received a link with the (I think) updated drivers for my notebook, provided by a mail of the manufacturer's support. Here is the link: https://mega.nz/#F!15MzVSIA!mc9UiGXuxy0UlCyaVTcvEQ!RlEDEDSL  I am trying to install the LAN and WLAN drivers, however in those folders I can't see a Setup.exe to install those 2 drivers. Can you help me installing them?

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I could boot Ubuntu from a pendrive and checked that the wifi intensity was low from 3-4 meters far from the wifi modem. Now I am having troubles in following these steps: "Look for the location of the Realtek chip, and note the routing of wires, one of which might serve as an antenna. Ordinary cellophane tape can be used to hold the antenna in position". How do I find the Realtek wifi chip and the antenna wire? Thank you.

Comment: Either find the service manual online, or find a video showing the insides of your laptop, or go to a technician who has that information, e.g. the one who probably caused the issue.